# Can't login to Asterisk from .NET

Tags: c#, networking, sip, voip, asterisk

I am trying to run the samples from [Asterisk.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asterisk-dotnet/) . When I try to run the following piece of code from Asterisk.NET.Test:

```
manager = new ManagerConnection(ASTERISK_HOST, ASTERISK_PORT, ASTERISK_LOGINNAME, ASTERISK_LOGINPWD);
manager.Login();
```

I always get the follwing message:

```
AuthenticationFailedException: Authentication failed ... at ManagerConnection.cs:line 1263
```

Which username and password should I use? 
I've tried "admin"/"admin"which I use for logging in at FreePBX web administration and with "admin"/"amp111", none of which work. I have not modified anything after installing AsteriskNow in VirtualBox. In the FreePBX web administration page every server status is green (ok).

Regards,
Tamas Ionut

Comment: There was (or at least used to be) a manager.conf file for Asterisk where you configured the MAPI accounts.

Comment: I am using the credentials from manager.conf from Asterisk, but with those I get this error. The credentials from manager.conf are username/password: "admin"/"amp111". When I connect from the FreePBX webpage at 198.168.2.63, I connect using "admin"/"admin" and it works. However, in the .NET sample application I'ved tried with both  set of credentials and none work (both throw thi exception).

Comment: I have figured out that not the login (authentication) was the problem but the actual connection to the asterisk server. I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837136/connecting-from-net-to-asterisk

Answer (score 0):

Start Telnet on machine from which you are trying to connect and run commands:

```
telnet 000.000.000.000 5038
ACTION:LOGIN
USERNAME:username
SECRET:password
EVENTS:ON
```

Where 000.000.000.000, username, password are server address, username and password.

If you receive message "authentication failed" most likely the connection from your machine's address is not allowed for the user 'username'. The addresses from which the user is allowed to establish connection are configured on the server in config files.