# Connecting from .NET to Asterisk

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, network-programming, asterisk

I am trying to connect from a .NET application to the Asterisk server, but the connection is not established. I am using the following code to connect to Asterisk:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.35"), 5038);
clientSocket.Connect(serverEndPoint);
```

and I get the following error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.35:5038
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or what is the solution to this?

Regards,
Tamash

Comment: Try `telnet 192.168.0.35 5038` from command line. Does that work?

Comment: By trying that command I get: "Asterisk Call Manger/1.1" but after around 5 seconds I get "Connection to host lost" and no interaction to the Asterisk server was made. By trying the C# code above I get the same error "A connection attempt failed because ...". Could it be some problems with the fact that Asterisk is deployed on VirtualBox? Can I deploy it live on my computer and maybe connect to the actual IP address of the machine? Any option (either in VM or live on another Linux machine) would work fine for me, if I could connect to it from C#.

Comment: These are different - with `telnet` you connect successfully, then the server drops your connection because it expects some message from you. With your C# code it looks like you are not even connecting.

Comment: DId you ever work this out?  I am in the exact same situation.  Asterisk on Virtual Box and it won't login.

Comment: @Jules999 Nope, did not managed to find a solution for that configuration. It was a long time ago, but I think we skipped VirtualBox altogether and went on a clean machine installation (without any VM).

Answer (score 0):

Check AMI in manager.conf. It should be like this:

```
 enabled = yes
 port = 5038
 bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
```